# How to write a SQL query with following parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

Table A

| Name | No.of book |
| --- | --- |
| John | 0 |
| John | 1 |
| Kate | 0 |

If there are two records as John with 0 and 1 value, I want to display record with 1 value
If no record with 1 value then display the record with 0 value

Result :

This is the result i want:

| Name | No.of book |
| --- | --- |
| Kate | 0 |
| John | 1 |

Comment: Why doesn't `WHERE [Name] = 'John';` work here..? Your expected results and description don't match the question, if I am honest.

Comment: Yes.. I just edited now.

Comment: `MAX()` would probably be the simplest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just want a `MAX`:

```
SELECT [Name],
       MAX([No.of book]) AS [No.of book] --This isn't a good name for a column, don't use names that require delimit identification
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT Name, NoOfBook
FROM TabelleA as src 
where NoOfBook=(select top 1 NoOfBook from TabelleA where Name=src.name order by 
NoOfBook desc)
```

which will return:

```
Name    No. of book
John    1
Kate    0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has more columns and you need an entire row you can use a window function plus handy `TOP(1) WITH TIES` Sql server feature

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by [Name] order by [No.of book] desc);
```